Old .img file wont boot up RPi? Any way to save/migrate the installation?
Thanks for checking. I have a purpose-built *.img from 2015 that I need to boot.
Back then, this img was used on a RP2 Model B.
I purchased a RP2 Model B from Amazon (apparently v1.2 if that helps, not sure what the old RP2 was)
After power-on, the RP2 gives me (Green led) 4 slow, 4 fast flashes -- repeat inf.
I tried to boot using an RP3 Model B -- I receive solid red led, no green flashes.
(Both of these RPi boot other IMGs when written using the imager, and the same micro sdcard)
Some important info:
The img was verified by dozens of people for integrity in 2015 when produced
The img was stored in a zip file, which extracts fine -- no storage issues
The img was written using the Raspberry pi imager 1.8.5 (have tried both options RP2 and RP4)
The imager does not complain about any errors, and writes + verifies no problem

I understand there was a change to the way the Pi boots between 2 and 4, which is why I have tried both settings. I guess it has something to do with old image and newer boot processes? If this is the case, is there any way to update or port my old to the new?
If I had access to an older Pi, would I be able to boot and in-place upgrade so I can boot on newer devices?
Could it work to IMG a usb stick, and boot a current kernel from the sdcard, and switch to the old distro using fstab?

It is impossible to run a 2015 OS on a Pi3. There is no recommended method to upgrade ANY Raspberry Pi OS - all require a fresh install.

If I did get an OLD RPi, boot from it, would I then be able to upgrade it? I believe the OS on the card was raspbian based. It was able to be updated with apt-get back in the day.
I will go to great lengths to make this work, so even if its a time consuming and overly complicated solution, sign me up!

If it unpacks fine, can you loop mount it on your computer and take whatever files you need?

I do have a .IMG file of the card, provided by the author (who is no longer in business and is unable to be of assistance). The problem is that some of the software and its configurations are proprietary for a corresponding piece of equipment.
